# Springboot requiring Jparepository interface to be implemented by a class before it runs

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am new to Springboot and currently trying to recreate the example from Baeldung where a simple fullstack [project](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-react-crud#spring-boot) is built using React as front end ().
From what I've gathered so far, when creating a repository using the JpaRepository interface, Spring basically creates a class in the background and I can then call the methods from JpaRepository.

However, after attempting this on my own, I get this error when I try to start my spring boot application: `No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.repository.ClientRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}`

I used a class implementation in the end to make the application run.
This is my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.200</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.6</version>
</dependency>
```

My repository interface:

```
package com.example.repository;

import com.example.model.Client;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

public interface ClientRepository extends JpaRepository<Client, Long> {
}
```

Controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/clients")
@EnableJpaRepositories
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.example","com.example.repository"})
public class ClientsController {

    private final ClientRepository clientRepository;

    public ClientsController(ClientRepository clientRepository){
        this.clientRepository = clientRepository;
    }

*** Remaining API methods ***
```

I have has to use a class implementation of JpaRepository to get enable the Springboot application to start. My question is: do I have to go on and fully implement my own data access layer since the default JpaRepository does not seem to be enough?

Comment: Try annotating your repository interface with `@Repository` .

Comment: I also tried that prior to asking this but it returned with the same error of not being able to find a repository bean. According to other sources, it's not required to add @Repository when you extend JpaRepository because Spring already recognises it as a Repository interface.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `@Repository` annotation for SpringBoot to create the Bean

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the following from the `ClientsController`

```
@EnableJpaRepositories
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.example","com.example.repository"})
```

And make sure that you add `@SpringBootApplication` to entry point of application.